# Should I use rescale parameters for data augmentation?

Tags: deep-learning, keras, tensorflow, computer-vision, convolutional-neural-network

I am using Keras library to build a CNN model. I want to use data augmentation for training data.

Should I use rescale parameters for data augmentation?

```
ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `rescale` argument byitself does not augment your data.

If you input pixels are in the range of [0,255], you can rescale to [0,1] using the code in your question. Just remember to do the same on all partitions of your dataset.

If you input is already in the range of [0,1], then obviously you should not rescale.

Comment: How can I know the range of the input?

Comment: Come on, use the fact that images are numbers and numpy array's can take care of them, combine with min, max...! A humble request, kindly read about DL before applying DL...

Comment: I am not using numpy array, I am reading the images from directory.

Comment: I cannot see the scale of the image from the image details.